# Responsive site looks different on client's location devices (Wordpress-Woocommerce)

Tags: php, wordpress, mobile, woocommerce, responsiveness

Facing a strange issue with site I am working with. The demo/live site looks good on all mobiles when I checked, but the live site looks zoomed out when viewed on phone by client and their customers (they are from another country). I tried responsinator, browser stack, iPhone & Android phones and asked friends from other countries to check in their mobile devices. But the site looks normal. Bcoz of this I am unable to analyze the issue. Its been more than a month so definitely caching is not a reason. Any help is appreciated.

[Demo site](http://%20teamsouls.com/blog)

[Live site](http://zuluinternational.com/)

[This is how it looks on client side](http://tinyurl.com/ont48br)

Comment: Looks fine for my on both sites as mobile, can you be sure the client isn't caching some old css? - perhaps force no cache for the stylesheet to see if this has an effect

Comment: Yes, i requested and they cleared the cache & cookies too. As its been a month I thought caching wont be an issue. I am now gonna try force no cache. Thank you for the tip.

Comment: Unfortunately clearing cache didn't solved the problem. Still it looks fine for me but not on client side.